# Using Range Values with Find

Tags: vba, excel

I am using .Find to look for a string, but the cells I want to search have formulae in them; what I want to compare in the result of those formulae. So far I have:

`cellrow = Range("A1:D4").Find("string").Row`

But it will return an error unless there is a genuine text 'string' in any of the cells. How can I modify this so that it is looking for the Value of each cell in the Range I have specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. There's a property in .Find that allows you to look for either formulae or values of the range.: LookIn